# How to expand a given range of numbers to include all numbers separated by a dash

Tags: r

I'm trying to expand a range of numbers currently separated by a dash to include all numbers.

The good news is that I found code (not mine) that helped with the following configuration:

"Ballroom 1-3" yields "Ballroom 1, Ballroom 2, Ballroom 3", which is what I want. The problem is that this is conditional on having no spaces before and after the dash. Currently, "Ballroom 1 - 3" returns "Ballroom 1 -3, Ballroom 1 - 3, Ballroom 1 - 3"; which is not the desired output.

Note that for several reasons, the spaces before and after the dashes have to be kept. Input of "Ballroom 1 - 3" has to remain the same.

```
## Dealing with Dash Seperated Sequences of Numbers

expand.dash <- function(dashed) {
  limits <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(dashed, '-')))
  seq(limits[1], limits[2])
}


expand.ballrooms <- function(txt) {
   str <- gsub('\\d+-\\d+', '%d', txt)
  dashed_str <- gsub('[a-zA-Z ]+', '', txt)
  sprintf(str, expand.dash(dashed_str))
}

expand.ballrooms("Ballroom 1-3")  
# this works but the line below fails to output the desired result 

expand.ballrooms("Ballroom 1 - 3")
# Result should be identical to the the output returned by the previous line.
```

While no error messages pop up, a space before and after the dash causes the output to just repeat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `expand.ballrooms` change this

`gsub('\\d+-\\d+', '%d', txt)`

to this:

`gsub('\\d+\\s*-\\s*\\d+', '%d', txt)`

Answer (score 1):

You can add an optional whitespace in the pattern in `gsub` in the function `expand.ballrooms`

```
gsub('\\d+\\s?-\\s?\\d+', '%d', txt)
```

The modified function would be

```
expand.dash <- function(dashed) {
  limits <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(dashed, '-')))
  seq(limits[1], limits[2])
}


expand.ballrooms <- function(txt) {
  str <- gsub('\\d+\\s?-\\s?\\d+', '%d', txt)
  dashed_str <- gsub('[a-zA-Z ]+', '', txt)
  sprintf(str, expand.dash(dashed_str))
}
```

and now this will work for both the cases

```
expand.ballrooms("Ballroom 1-3")
#[1] "Ballroom 1" "Ballroom 2" "Ballroom 3"

expand.ballrooms("Ballroom 1 - 3")
#[1] "Ballroom 1" "Ballroom 2" "Ballroom 3"
```

Comment: Thank you for the elaboration